# I need one word for "Real Stories"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I want to say Stories of goodwill or stories about goodwill, which is real and interesting. Need a strong word which sound good to ears

Answer (score 1):

"[Testimonials](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/testimonial)" has more positive connotations, and is similar to "endorsements".

Answer (score 0):

Try [**anecdotes**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anecdote):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : a usually short narrative of an interesting, amusing, or biographical incident
>
> // Like many Jesuits who then ate most of their meals in refectories, McKenzie was a master raconteur with endless *anecdotes*, stories, and one-liners.
> — Margaret O'Brien Steinfels, *Commonweal*, 11 Sept. 2009

As the definition says, they are *usually* short, but they don't always have to be.